# How to study a javascript-based roulette's pattern?

Tags: probability

So recently I've been playing on an online roulette and after some time on this site I detected a pattern the roulette has, like I have the feeling when the green will come out for example. Is it possible to create a script based on the roulette's code and that way getting at least probabilities of what will come next? Should I know JavaScript?

Comment: Do you have access to the underlying source code? This doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: I think I do. The site has a section where it shows the code that roulette uses in order to demonstrate the 'randomness'.

Answer (score 1):

javascript is client side, it runs in your local browser.  The only use you might have is to have a page you have written, with javascript, to take a snapshot, or parse through the roulette site page and extract the wheel numbers which you could then perform your analysis on. The wheel numbers are coming from their server (not from javascript.)  If this a real (money) site, it won't work, the numbers will be random enough such that any advantage you might (read: won't) extract will be more than offset by the enormous 5.5% house edge on the bets. That feeling in your in your gut is simply you randomly being correct a couple of times. Your time would be better spent writing a limit poker machine learning model.

Comment: Now that I remember, there is a chrome extension that predicts the color coming out but AFTER the countdown reach to 0, how is it possible? Is it possible to take advantage and edit that extension to predict before the wheel runs?

Comment: Is this a real money site, or just somebody's for-fun javascript roulette game?

Comment: It's a real one. I started with a free dollar from the site and made 80

Comment: Here's some free advice: 1) You will never beat roulette in the long run online or in a casino.  2) That code they showed you regarding how they generate random numbers may be bogus.  Don't forget they know your bet, you don't know their code.  3) It's in their best interest for you to feel like you can win. 4) Go ahead and try and cash out that $80 bucks, see just how easily they will cash you out.  You cannot win, and you shouldn't try. Best of luck.

Comment: What about the extension I'm talking about? I tried it and its 100% accurate. Can it be modified for earlier prediction? How did the guy coded it?

Comment: If it is a javascript chrome extension you should look at his or her code.

Comment: Alright, will do it when I'm back home. Thanks for your time

Comment: The add on probably reads the server response string, possibly an ajax response, as xml or even plain text.  After it has left the server it's no longer secret.  It then parses that response and "predicts" the number milliseconds before the page element is updated, or forces the page to delay it's update as a kind of magic trick effect.